# ¿Cómo usar responsivevoice en TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Estoy intentando utilizar la `responsivevoice` en un proyecto hecho en `TypeScript`. Lo importe y añadí a un archivo `TS` para poder usarlo, sin embargo, no me reconoce las variables y funciones que intento utilizar. Además, al cargar el proyecto este arroja el mapeo que realiza responsivevoice cuando se carga en la web validando que fue importando y cargando en el  navegador.

Mappeo:

`

```
Voice support ready
responsiveVoice.js:718 Mapped UK English Female to Google UK English Female
responsiveVoice.js:718 Mapped UK English Male to Google UK English Male
responsiveVoice.js:718 Mapped US English Female to Google US English
responsiveVoice.js:729 Mapped Spanish Female to es fallback voice
responsiveVoice.js:729 Mapped French Female to fr fallback voice
responsiveVoice.js:718 Mapped Deutsch Female to Google Deutsch
responsiveVoice.js:729 Mapped Italian Female to it fallback voice
responsiveVoice.js:729 Mapped Hungarian Female to hu fallback voice
responsiveVoice.js:729 Mapped Serbian Male to sr fallback voice
responsiveVoice.js:729 Mapped Croatian Male to hr fallback voice
responsiveVoice.js:729 Mapped Bosnian Male to bs fallback voice
responsiveVoice.js:729 Mapped Fallback UK Female to en-GB fallback voice
```

`
De esta manera estoy intentando utilizarlo. (Como lo usaba en un archivo js y html convencional) :

```
`
function voiceMessage(message) {
      setTimeout(function() {
          responsiveVoice.speak(message, "Spanish Male");
          message = encodeURIComponent(message);
          var url = "http://"
      }, 2);
    }
`
```

y el error aparece como:

```
`
        app.js:8 Uncaught ReferenceError: responsiveVoice is not defined
        at eval (app.js:8)

`
```

Código TS:

```
`import "jquery";

import "voiceAPI";

function voiceMessage(message) {
  setTimeout(function() {
      responsiveVoice.speak(message, "Spanish Male");
      message = encodeURIComponent(message);
      var url = "http://"
  }, 2);
}

$(document).ready(function(){

  voiceMessage("Hola Mundo!");
});
`
```

Código Html con el SystemJS.Config:

```
<script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.js"></script>
<script>
    // set our baseURL reference path
    SystemJS.config({
            packages: {
                '/': {
                    main: 'app.js'
                }
            },
            map: {
                "jquery": "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
                "voiceAPI": "node_modules/responsiveVoice/responsiveVoice.js"
            },
            defaultExtension: true
        })
        // loads /js/main.js
    SystemJS.import('app.js');
</script>
```

Espero puedan ayudarme por favor, gracias.

Comment: Ya veo... No estoy seguro.. .Pero intenta con `import * as responsiveVoice from 'voiceAPI'` en vez de solo `import 'voiceAPI'` y me avisas.

Comment: Me sale  `Cannot find module 'voiceAPI'`

Comment: Has considerado actualizar tu versión de Angular? Webpack tiene sus ventajas sobre SystemJS

Comment: No estoy utilizando Angular amigo, es puro TypeScript